# Control API exposure - Spring

Tags: java, spring, vue.js, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an application made in Spring + Vue js and I have questions regarding the exposure of endpoints on the web.

After I'm authenticated in the system, when for example I try to access localhost:8080/contracts he is bringing the response in JSON format on the screen, but I would like to block this exposure, even on account of data security.

How can I best control this? Do I do for Spring Security?

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
package br.com.braxxy.adm.brxmind.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import br.com.braxxy.pls.web.user.CustomUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("br.com.braxxy.adm.brxmind.security")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    CustomizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService mongoUserDetails() {
        return new CustomUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService = mongoUserDetails();
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "favicon.ico", "/materialize/**", "/style/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/new-user").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/new-user").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable().formLogin().successHandler(customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true").usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password").and().logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/assets/css/**", "/assets/css/vendor/**", "/assets/fonts/**", "/assets/images/**", "/assets/js/**", "/assets/js/vendor/**", "/assets/js/ui/**", "/assets/js/pages/**");
    }
    


}

[![Response API][1]][1]
```

Comment: Do you mean having roles in the application and only some users are able to see that?

Comment: What I want to block is the visualization of json when, for example, I access the endpoint /contract, because when I do that, it is returning json with sensitive information, so if the user tries to access the endpoint /contract via the URL, I can't present the data for him.

Comment: adding `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/contract").hasRole("ADMIN")` ?

Comment: There is no way to prevent the end user from doing anything with data you provide. If you don't want them to see the sensitive information, you shouldn't be returning it. (As a side note, you're re-declaring several Spring Security defaults; just let the defaults be default, and avoid changing things like the username parameter for no particular reason.)

Comment: I think the only way to control this is by authentication via token right?

I thought there was some simpler way to block this for the user :(

Comment: One way can be - in your controller, add a check to validate the roles/username of user. If the logged in user matches required criteria, call service method, else return empty json. But this would require hardcoding inside controller. Better approach would be to have role level check and annotate with @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('admin')")

Comment: I still don't understand your use case. When is the `/contract` endpoint useful then? If you don't want it, delete it. If you want just some users to reach it then take advantage of app roles (`.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/contract").hasRole("ADMIN")`, as already suggested).